# Combine two SQL queries with a different status column in each

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am using VBA to generate SQL queries in Access.  I have two SQL queries that return two lists of items with a status column that shows Required or Optional:

```
"SELECT *, 'Required' as status FROM tblMain WHERE " & where_1
"SELECT *, 'Optional' as status FROM tblMain WHERE " & where_2
```

*where_1* and *where_2* are string variables I build within the VBA--it's not really important what they are though.

What I'd like to do is have one combined list, and if an item shows in both lists, I'd like that item to show just once with a "Required" status ("Required" trumps "Optional").  I started with a union query, but I'm not sure how to eliminate the duplicate rows with the "Optional" statuses.

```
SELECT * FROM
((SELECT *, 'Required' as status FROM tblMain WHERE where_1)
UNION
(SELECT *, 'Optional' as status FROM tblMain WHERE where_2))
```

I'm thinking a DISTINCT or possibly a FIRST could be used, but unfortunately I'm having trouble working out the syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you eliminate IDs selected in the first statement from the second statement.

```
SELECT *, 'Required' as status FROM tblMain WHERE where_1
UNION
SELECT *, 'Optional' as status FROM tblMain WHERE where_2
AND ID Not IN (SELECT ID FROM tblMain WHERE where_1)
```

Comment: He didn't say that he has IDs at all.

Comment: I do have IDs.  This looks great--I'll test it now.  Thanks!

Comment: This worked great, though unfortunately with the data I had, the query ran pretty slow causing a delay (20 seconds or so) in the front end refreshing.  I ended up using VBA to dump all the IDs to a temp table and running the query off of that, but this did work.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

you could use `MAX`.

```
SELECT *, MAX(status) FROM
((SELECT *, 'Required' as status FROM tblMain WHERE where_1)
UNION
(SELECT *, 'Optional' as status FROM tblMain WHERE where_2))
GROUP BY all_other_columns
```

Be aware that you have to replace 'all_other_comuns' by your actual columns.

Comment: When you run MAX against a string like that, does it go by alphabetical order?  I'll test this.  Thanks!

Comment: @rryanp It does so in any DB I have used to this day, but I haven't used Access yet.

Comment: I tested this and got an error--I didn't troubleshoot too much, but I think maybe Access may have trouble using Max with string values, as I tried it against an integer field, and it worked fine.  I actually used it in another place in my DB, so thanks!

Comment: @rryanp well good to know. If you want to, you can substitute `Required` and `Optional` with numbers and do a `CASE WHEN` to produce the Strings afterward. (Or if you process the result in a program afterward you can stick to numbers anyway).

Answer (score 0):

Since all of the data is coming from a single table, the best option may be to move the logic from a second query to the `status` column itself:

```
SELECT *, iif(condition1,'Required','Optional') as status 
FROM tblMain
```

This way each row in `tblMain` is only retrieved once in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without a union:

```
SELECT *,
       (case when where_1 then 'Required'
             when where_2 then 'Optional'
        end) as status
FROM tblMain
WHERE (where_1) or (where_2)
```

Alas, though, you don't have the case statement in ACCESS, so you use iif() instead:

```
SELECT *,
       iif(where_1, 'Required', 'Optional') as status
FROM tblMain
WHERE (where_1) or (where_2)
```

Comment: SQL is a generic tag, the particular flavour required is MS Access, so no case, I am afraid.